# Bootstrap styles isn't applied to HTML

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="txtTitle" class="control-label">
            <p class="text-info">Page Title</p>
        </label>
        <asp:textbox id="txtTitle" tabindex="14" runat="server" MaxLength="60" TextMode="SingleLine" CssClass="form-control input-sm"></asp:textbox>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this peace of HTML - it should be inline form, but styles for `form-inline` isn't applied, even if bootstap is included.

[image]

I've tried it with my "local" bootstap and with bootstrap from [cdn](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css) but nothing is working correctly.

Where can be my problem?

Comment: do you get any warnings or errors in the console?

Comment: @GiovanniLeGrand only about `fonts`

Comment: hmmm looks like bootstrap is doing its job tho

Comment: where it is not working? desktop or mobile view?

Comment: Is the class control-label present in the css file ? You can check the console tab of the chrome developer tools, to see if there are any errors.

Comment: @demo reproduce issue on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Bootstrap's](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) documentation:

> Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a ) for left-aligned and inline-block controls. **This only applies to forms within viewports that are at least 768px wide.**

If you will run following code in **Full Page** mode you will see that `inline-form` styles are being applied.

```css
.control-label .text-info {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="txtTitle1" class="control-label">
            <p class="text-info">Page Title</p>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="txtTitle1" tabindex="14" MaxLength="60" TextMode="SingleLine" class="form-control input-sm">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="txtTitle2" class="control-label">
            <p class="text-info">Page Title</p>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="txtTitle2" tabindex="14" MaxLength="60" TextMode="SingleLine" class="form-control input-sm">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="txtTitle3" class="control-label">
            <p class="text-info">Page Title</p>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="txtTitle3" tabindex="14" MaxLength="60" TextMode="SingleLine" class="form-control input-sm">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and that's why I ask OP where is having the problem, so if its on desktop, this doesn't apply

Comment: @dippas, yes, you are right... I have this "form" in `iframe` which is smaller that `768px`